# How to bind only keypresses and not when key is held down in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind

I'm not too sure how I'd explain it in the title, but I want to bind a key in Tkinter and not have it work if the key is being held down.

For example, `root.bind("<space>", doaction)` I'm trying to run `doaction` only when the spacebar is clicked and not held down. Is there any way to do this? I've tried KeyRelease too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can do. With respect to keyboard keys, you can bind on `<KeyPress>` and `<KeyRelease>`. If you want more, you'll have to set global variables and/or timers that are set or reset on one of those, and then checked on the other.

The problem is that on some systems, keyboards may send a sequence of press/release pairs while holding a key, while other systems may send just a single press and release. There's no good way to abstract that out since it may happen at the hardware level.